Storing SimpleFeatureStore to shapefile when the attribute names are longer than 10 characters
When I, with the code below, try to export a SimpleFeatureSource to a SHAPEfile attribute names with more the 10 characters will be truncated, due to the shapefile format
(e.g FEATURE_TEXT -> FEATURE_TE).
This is done when I create the ShapeFileDatastore.createSchema()...
Then I try to store the data, the FEATUR_TE will be empty because there is no attribute FEATURE_TE in my original data just FEATURE_TEXT.
What am I missing between creating the ShapeFileDataStore.createSchema() and adding the features to the ShapeFileDataStore?
File directory =  new File(path);
ShapefileDataStore newDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore) dataStoreFactory.createNewDataStore(params);
newDataStore.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
newDataStore.createSchema(TYPE); //Här sker truncate
Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");

String typeName = newDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = newDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
    SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;

    featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
    try {
        featureStore.addFeatures(simpleFeatureCollection);
        transaction.commit();

    } catch (Exception problem) {
        problem.printStackTrace();
        transaction.rollback();

    } finally {
        transaction.close();
        pgDatastore.dispose();
        newDataStore.dispose();
    }
}


ShapeFiles can't have attribute names that exceed 10 characters because memory and disk are very expensive. Please use a modern format with out these issues like a geopackage.
